# PHP array for google chart; loop thru array and group by 2

Tags: php, arrays

(In between Christmas meals) I am again stuck with the loop through array and group by logic.
here is the array I am given

```
$aTest = Array
(
    Array
        (
            'date' => 2017-05-04,
            'period' => 'period2',
            'category' => 'Indoor room',
            'score' => 1
        ),

    Array
        (
            'date' => 2017-05-04,
            'period' => 'period5',
            'category' => 'Indoor room',
            'score' => 1
        ),

    Array
        (
            'date' => 2017-05-04,
            'period' => 'period2',
            'category' => 'Indoor room',
            'score' => 2
        ),

    Array
        (
            'date' => 2017-05-04,
            'period' => 'period4',
            'category' => 'Indoor room',
            'score' => 1
        ),

     Array
        (
            'date' => 2017-05-03,
            'period' => 'period5',
            'category' => 'Gym Class',
            'score' => 1
        ),

    Array
        (
            'date' => 2017-05-03,
            'period' => 'period1',
            'category' => 'Gym Class',
            'score' => 1
        ),

     Array
        (
            'date' => 2017-05-03,
            'period' => 'period4',
            'category' => 'Indoor room',
            'score' => 1
        )
        );
```

This time I like group by category and sum the score group by period.  Y-axis will be the category and X-axis will be the period. In the end I need this for a google chart

```
/*period, total indoor, total gym, 'total indoor', 'total gym'*/
array(
['Period1', 0,1,'0','1'],
['Period2', 3,0,'3','0'],
['Period3', 0, 0,'0','0'],
['Period4', 4,0,'4','0'],
['Period5', 1,1,'1','1']
 )
```

I have this php code:

```
    foreach ($aTest as $value) {
            //echo $value['period'].' - '.$value['score'].'<br/>';

            if (empty($output[$value]['period']))
                $output[$value]['period'] = ['Period1' => 0, 'Period2' => 0, 'Period3' =>0, 'Period4' => 0, 'Period5' => 0];

   if(empty($output[$value]['category']))
        $output[$value['catgeory']] = ['Gym Class' => 0, 'Indoor room' =>0];

            $output[$value['category']] += $value['score'];
        }

        ksort($output);
```

but this only totals the score by Category and not by period.
I think I need to loop through the periods as well, but how?

Answer (score 1):

- You have a wrong logic here.

> ```
> if (empty($output[$value]['period']))
>                 $output[$value]['period'] = ['Period1' => 0, 'Period2' => 0, 'Period3' =>0, 'Period4' => 0, 'Period5' => 0];
> ```

that **$value** is an array and you try to check **$output[$value]**

- I saw that you don't have any line sum periods Value.
- I have a solution for your data. 
  What is my code do??
- Sum score of the **period** by the **category**
- For each merge **period** and **category** score to an array using **arraySort** category to set position of these category scores values

> ```
> $temp = [];
> $output = []; 
> foreach($aTest as $value){
>   $period = $value['period'];
>   $category = $value['category'];
>
>   // Create default values
>   if (empty($temp[$period])){
>         $temp[$period] = [];
>   }
>   if(empty($temp[$period][$category])){
>       $temp[$period][$category] = 0;
>   }
>   //Sum score 
>   $temp[$period][$category] += $value['score'];
> }
>
> //After Forech we have an array with ['period name' => ['category name' => score]]; 
> //Sort values of the category change it if you want, you can add more option such as (item type for add '' to values)
> $arraySort = [
>   "Indoor room", //total indoor,
>   "Gym Class", // total gym, 
>   "Indoor room", //'total indoor', 
>   "Gym Class" //'total gym'
> ];
> foreach($temp as $period => $catsScore){
>   $periodItem = [$period];
>   foreach($arraySort as $cat){
>       $periodItem[] = $catsScore;
>   }
>   $output[] = $periodItem;
> }
> ```

Comment: you help me out a lot I think I need your first part of the code you wrote for my actual array. But I don't get your 2nd part of the code $arraySort, here I get arrays in array '[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => period1
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Gym Class] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Gym Class] => 1
                )

        ) etc' 
I wil reread what you have provided, thanks

Comment: 2nd part i have sort these category because i think some time input category not ordered.

Comment: will try it out but your first part is what i like to use superb!

Comment: i am trying your second part to sort the output array to a specific for the x-axis (break, period1, period2, lunch, period3, period5, period6, finish)

Comment: well I am having a problem sorting the periods to specific order see my post with your 2nd part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997395/how-to-sort-a-php-associative-array-to-a-specific-order

Comment: These answer seem as like part 2 of my solution